# How to determine if user is beginning new word in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you, with JS or jQuery, determine if what the user is typing is a new word?

What I want to do:

I am writing a documentation tool with autocompletion for different types. If you type f.e. `@` it will populate Java Classes in a box, `#` would populate test classes, etc. Now I don't want to populate these values, if the user is writing something like an email like `yourname@domain.com`. So I need the values to populate only when it's the beginning of the word.

I am aware of keydown, keyup events, etc. I just don't know how to check for this certain kind of event properly.

One way would be to save every typed letter in a variable and then check if the previous "letter" was a space and if it was, we know it's a new word. Is this the best/most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Check if previous character is space...

Comment: Or any whitespace for that matter.

Comment: you don't have to remember previous letters, on keyup if the value is white space listen for the next keystroke and do your thing..

Comment: @javabot, do you mean you would implement another listener with .one inside the .on keyup listener?

Comment: Can't you just use .on('keyup') and retrieve the current value of the input? (using a set of regex if necessary)

Comment: @briosheje please check the "mail" example. If you would just check the current input, then it would be not really user friendly. Then you would populate the list everytime you would write, f.e. an @ inside a word(every email)

Comment: "If you type f.e. @ it will populate Java Classes in a box, # would populate test classes, etc." Like in Sublime... ?

Comment: No, I'm not getting your point. So you want to autocomplete only if the input is blank and the user is writing the very first letter?

Comment: no, the very first of every word. if you have a sentence then you need to check every first letter of each word, if it is an @ then it will populate the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check what's before the `@` in the input box, using `selectionStart`:

```js
onload = function() {
  
  
  var io = document.getElementById("io");
  
  io.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if(e.charCode == 64 && (
        io.selectionStart == 0 || io.value[io.selectionStart-1].match(/\s/)))
      
      document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML = "autocomplete!";
    
    else 

      document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML = "";
      
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="io">
<div id="ac"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for and it works perfectly fine! Thanks really much

Answer (score 0):

[Try this JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0xva0dup/1/) I'm performing the check like so:

```
var text = $("#test").val();
if (text.length == 0 || text.charAt(text.length - 1).match(/[\s\b]/)) {
    $("#result").html("new word");
} else {
    $("#result").html("no new word");
}
```

You can easily adapt the `.match()` pattern if you like to include other characters as "whitespaces" (e.g. curly braces) for your Editor.

Answer (score -1):

One solution will be like this :

1- declare a variable "newWord = true"

2- with keydown event check if the key pressed is a space

if YES : newWord = true

if NO : newWord = false

```
var newWord=true;
$("#textarea").keydown(function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 32){
          newWord=true;
     }else{
          newWord=false;
          switch(e.keyCode){
               //work to do
          }
     }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming text is entered in a text input with id="txtchangedetection":

```
   $("#txtchangedetection").change(function(){
        console.log("The text has been changed.");
      });
/*This is `JQuery`*/
```

I've understood you want to detect word changes in the input. Please precise if I'm wrong. What do you mean by 'new word' ?

Answer (score -1):

use keypress on your input field... populate the array inside the if with your special chars

```
if(prev == 13 || prev == 32 || $('#doc').val().length==0 || prev==null){
    listen = true;
}else{
    listen = false;
}

prev = e.which;

if(listen && $.inArray(String.fromCharCode(e.which),["@","#"]) != -1){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("populate box here");
    listen = false;
    prev = null;
}
```

the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6okfqub4/